# Is there a good plugin to highlight map areas?

Tags: javascript, plugins, resize, area

can anyone suggest a JavaScript plugin like maphighlight but more custom,
with option to re-size the main image and the areas coordinates??

Answer (score 0):

You can use **polygon** in google map v3 to highlight the area with different colors.

[Google map v3 polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple)